# How to translate "be ready to <do a favor, chore, ...>"? (in the sense of willingness, not preparedness)

Tags: single-word-requests

If I've been asked to do something, or recognize something that ought to be done, but I'm neither obligated to do it, nor particularly eager to do it, but I *am* willing to help out doing it, how do I indicate that notion?

Let's say, I've been asked, whether I'd participate in a study by taking a short survey. (I.e. answering a bunch of questions.)

In English, I could probably say

> I'm ready to *<do that>*.

e.g.

> I'm ready to take your survey.
>
> I'm ready to participate in your study.

or in German

> Ich bin bereit, *<das zu tun>*.

e.g.

> Ich bin bereit, an Ihrer Umfrage / Studie teilzunehmen.

to express that, but depending on context, in both English and German that can be misunderstood as me being already prepared to do the thing, i.e., that I could start right now, which might not be the case, or might not be what I want to express.

I believe the Esperanto

> Mi pretas *<fari tion>*.

or

> Mi estas preta *<fari tion>*.

e.g.

> Mi pretas partonpreni vian esploran enketon.
>
> Mi estas preta respondi al via demandaro.

suffers from this even more, in that it can only be interpreted like I'm already prepared for the activity.

On the other hand,

> Mi volas *<fari tion>*.

seems to me too much like it's my *wish*, while actually, I might just want to help out, without having an actual desire to do the activity *per se*.

I think I'm looking for an auxillary verb or adjective, but I'm also open to other ways to phrase this.

Comment: It's kinda hard to ask about something that I can't even express precisely in the site's language (English) nor in my mother tongue (German). But who knows, maybe this is another case where Esperanto _does_ have a very precise way to express something not-so-uncommon that some other languages lack dedicated words for.

Comment: Also, if you know of a better way to express de described notion in German or English, please let me know in the comments. :-)

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to say. You are ready, but not really? Could you provide a sentence in any language describing that? Or a situation.

Comment: "Ready" in the sense that I'm not unwilling, but not ready in the sense of "already prepared" / "I can start right now". "Willing" in the sense that I'd volunteer, but not in the sense that I absolutely _want_ to do whatever was asked to do. Does that make any sense @EduardoTrápani?

Comment: As for a situation: Someone asks in a chat group who would be willing to participate in a study by filling out a survey. They didn't yet link to the survey, but ask to send them a private message if one would like to participate. I don't enjoy filling out surveys, but I think the study is a worthwhile cause, so I'd like to volunteer the 10 to 40 minutes this would take. What do I write them in the private message?

Comment: ([That](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/how-to-translate-be-ready-to-do-a-favor-chore-in-the-sense-of-willin?noredirect=1#comment5922_5557) is in fact the actual situation that brought up that question for me. To see the call for participation, join the [Esperanto - Deutsch](https://de.telegramo.org/) group on Telegram and then follow [this link](https://t.me/c/1037896062/15787).)

Comment: _mi pretas fari tion_ is ok. I guess you could say _mi pretas, kvankam mi ne ne emas_ if you really want to let them know.

Comment: Ah, am I then mistaken that "preti" means that one is prepared to start right now? @EduardoTrápani

Comment: "preti" means simply "esti preta", doesn't it? And all definitions of "preta" [in ReVo](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/preta) and [in PIV](http://vortaro.net/#preta) seem to imply the "being prepared" / "being ready to start" notion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to say this is with *volonte*.

> Mi volonte plenigus vian demandaron.

You can use *preta* as suggested but it sounds somewhat more formal and reserved. I'd use it if I didn't feel like doing something but I would if necessary.

If you're volunteering simply use *volonte*.

Comment: Bonvenon ĉe [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! Dankon pro via respondo. Mi kredas ke mi uzos tion.

Answer (score 4):

I myself would simply use ”Mi pretas...” for willingness as well as preparedness. For example ”Se via fratino ne sukcesos akiri bileton, mi pretus doni la mian al ŝi.” The message here is not that ”I” is practically or mentally prepared to give their ticket away, but rather that ”I” would be willing to do so, because the sister deserves it more or similarily.

If you look at the second definition in PIV (vortaro.net): ”Estanta en taŭgaj dispozicioj por ion fari tuj” there are examples that suggest this use: ”Mi estas preta riski la vivon” and ”Mi estas preta iri por vi piede al la fino de la mondo.”

If you want to make it clear that you aren’t ready to do something right now, but willing to, use the -us form. For example ”Ĉu vi pretus respondi demandojn pri via sano?” or ”Mi pretus translokiĝi al la kamparo se tio estas kion li bezonas”.

Answer (score 2):

Alia eventuala diro estas:

> Mi konsentas fari tion.

Tiel oni ne indikas fervoron, pretecon aŭ tro grandan volon.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want to say something like

> Mi emas (fari tion).

or (maybe closer to the german word *geneigt*)

> Mi inklinas ...

Comment: Mi kredas, ke nek _emas_, nek _inklinas_ signifas ekzakte tio, kion mi volas esprimi, sed eble ili estas la plej proksimaj al ĝi. Do unue mi atendu pliajn respondojn.

Comment: Downvoting without explanation doesn't help anyone to appreciate the quality of an answer. Neither does it help OP to find the best answer to the question nor does it help me to learn what's wrong with my answer. Therefore I consider it immature and absolutely not helpful for this site.